# Multiple int main()'s?

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and im trying to expose myself to simple additions and subtractions. However I cant seem to get this function(s) running. Any input would be well appreciated. I also accept constructive criticism :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << " I have a qustion for you Devante. Here it is . . . if you add the word two to the number 2, what do you get ?";
    int x = 4;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Correct, the correct answer is " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << " Since you got the answer right this time, lets see if you can subtract. What is 6 - 6 ? ";
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Correct, the answer is " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, but you can only have one `main` function.

Comment: *im trying to expose myself* - Are you sure that is legal in your country?

Comment: Ok thanks. Also,  Is there any way I can put two questions within this ? Btw, im asking what is 2+2 & 6-6 basically.

Comment: 4 and zero is the answer

Comment: Just put the questions one after the other? By the way, you aren't actually checking if the answers are correct.

Comment: Ideally you should only ask 1 question per question post.

Comment: You forgot to explain what you're trying to do. We cannot determine that by reading code that — by your own admission — does not actually do that thing!

Answer (score 7):

You can only have one `main` function in  a program.

What you can do is...

Put the code in those functions in two differently named functions.
Call them from `main`.

```
int test1()
{
    std::cout << " I have a qustion for you Devante. Here it is . . . if you add the word two to the number 2, what do you get ?";
    int x = 4;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Correct, the correct answer is " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int test2()
{   
    std::cout << " Since you got the answer right this time, lets see if you can subtract. What is 6 - 6 ? ";
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Correct, the answer is " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`main` represents the entry point of your program. You cannot have multiple.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have more than one definition of **any** function.

Comment: Factually incorrect. You can have more than one definition of the same function.